# Nested REST or CAML code to list "NOT-IN" List Join Logic. Possible?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, custom-list, rest, caml

I'm thinking this is possible in SPO 2013?

Two Custom Lists.  Submitted and Universe (common field employee number)

One qualifier condition that applies to both .. dept = Sales

I need to list Universe (from dept sales) that are currently not in Submitted (from dept sales)

In other words, Dept Sales entries  yet to be Submitted.

And, I would like to construct two button (per row) the enables users to View and Delete entries from Submitted per row.

I would image I need nested REST or Complex CAML Where code right?

I'm looking for code sample.. preferably jQuery with CAML.

Comment: What are types of the fields you mentioned? `EmployeeNumber` is Text? And `Dept` is Lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you need something like this:

```
select * from Universe
where Dept = @SalesDeptId and EmployeeNumber not in 
    (select EmployeeNumber from Submitted where Dept=@SalesDeptId)
```

In SharePoint JSOM you can achieve this result with two CAML queries:

```
var salesDeptId = // put here your sales department id
var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
query.set_viewXml("<View><Query>" + new CamlBuilder.Where().LookupField("Dept").Id().EqualTo(salesDeptId).ToString() + "</Query></View>");

var items = submittedList.getItems(query);
context.load(items);

context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
  var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
  var expressions = [];
  while(enumerator.moveNext())
  {
    var item = enumerator.get_current();
    expressions.push(CamlBuilder.Expression().TextField("EmployeeNumber").NotEqualTo(item.get_item('EmployeeNumber'));

  }
  expressions.push(CamlBuilder().Expression().LookupField("Dept").Id().EqualTo(salesDeptId));

  var whereObject = new CamlBuilder.Where();
  var where = whereObject.All.apply(whereObject, expressions).ToString()

  var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
  query.set_viewXml("<View><Query>" + where + "</Query></View>");
  var notSubmittedItems = universeList.getItems(query);

  context.load(notSubmittedItems);

  context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    var enumerator = notSubmittedItems.getEnumerator();
    while(enumerator.moveNext())
    {
      var item = enumerator.get_current();
      // do whatever you need with the not submitted items
    }
  },
  HandleError);
},
HandleError);

functionHandleError(s,a) {
  alert('ERROR! ' + a.get_message());
}
```

In the example above, CAML queries are generated using opensource [CamlJs](http://camljs.codeplex.com) project (`CamlBuilder`). It is very handy for working with CAML in SP.

If you don't want to use it for some reasons, the CAML queries are as follows (you will have to put some additional efforts to compose that queries, especially the second one):

Query to Submitted list:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="Dept" LookupId="TRUE" />
    <Value Type="Number">
      {put sales department number here}
    </Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

Query to Universe list:

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Dept" LookupId="TRUE" />
      <Value Type="Number">
        {put sales department number here}
      </Value>
    </Eq>
    <And>
      <Neq>
        <FieldRef Name="EmployeeNumber" />
        <Value Type="Text">
          {not submitted employee number 1 from first query}
        </Value>
      </Neq>
      <And>
        <Neq>
          <FieldRef Name="EmployeeNumber" />
          <Value Type="Text">
            {not submitted employee number 2 from first query}
          </Value>
        </Neq>
        ....
        <Neq>
          <FieldRef Name="EmployeeNumber" />
          <Value Type="Text">
            {not submitted employee number N from first query}
          </Value>
        </Neq>
      </And>
    </And>
  </And>
</Where>
```

To simplify working with js and Client Side Object Model, I would also recommend to take a look on the following projects:

- [TypeScript Definitions for SharePoint 2013](http://sptypescript.codeplex.com)
- [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com)

P.S. Affiliation disclaimer: I'm author of CamlJs project and one of authors of SPTypeScript project.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking this should depend on your experience in javascript. In any way this is about crating so called custom solution.

Persoanlly I prefer to use javascript based approach in these cases. First, it doesn't require you to have admin rights on the portal. Second, it is much more fluent than just caml. Last, the solution could be functioning without full page reloading (with ajax).

Microsoft is thinking in the same way. In 2013 version they introduced new technology called ClientSideRendering (CSR) instead of CAML representation. Now it's turn to deal with CAML requests.

As for the nested REST I think it's possible not to use nested requests and work with two collections, but this requires you to write javascript code to analyse data.